# Changing Redirect Match to Rewritw rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

For one of my website I have to change the redirect match to rewrite rule to keep the modules in sync and alternatively remove the mod_alias .

I tried few but could not succeed can someone please help here.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mywebsite.com [NC]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1/$2/$4
RedirectMatch 301 ^/search/page/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/?s&paged=$1
```

Tried to use the mod_rewrite but no success

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1/$2/$4 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/search/page/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/?s&paged=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(.*)$ /$1/$2/$4 [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/page/(.+)$ /?s&paged=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: It worked for few urls but failed for few but the redirect match works for all the urls. I believe the rewritecond needs more tweak?

Comment: Try to test in Chrome dev tool and then tell me some example URLs for which it didn't work.